# infinite yield possible on 'Players.shaz:WaitForChild("Values")' im trying to make it so when the player claims the booth it turns bool value to true

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local claim = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.StandMesh.Claim
```

> This will trigger the Proximty Prompt.

```
claim.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
local screengui = player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild('Popups')
local popup = player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild('Popups').ClaimedBooth
local bool = player:WaitForChild('Values').Claimed
```

Comment: Is there an object named "Values" in the Player? Is it spelled correctly? Does it actually exist?

Comment: Yes i made inside playerscripts player = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer

if game:IsLoaded() then
 playervalues = Instance.new('Folder',player)
 playervalues.Name = 'Values'
 bool = Instance.new('BoolValue',playervalues)
 bool.Name = 'Claimed'

end

Comment: If you playtest the game for me will you check in the Explorer if inside the Player folder and open the folder called shaz(your username) and check if there is an object inside called Values?

Comment: yes there is and inside it is Claimed

Comment: The reason that its an infinite yield is because for all the server knows that values doesn't even exist. You're creating an object client-side and trying to access it server-side which would not work, it would return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Infinite yield possible" is a warning. It lets you know that your code is unsafe, and that when this code executed, the `Values` object didn't exist (or was spelled incorrectly) for more than 5 seconds, and `player:WaitForChild('Values')` could not resolve to an object.

The documentation for [Instance:WaitForChild()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild) has this to say :

> **Notes**
>
> - If a call to this function exceeds 5 seconds without returning, and no timeOut parameter has been specified, a warning will be printed to the output that the thread may yield indefinitely; this warning takes the form Infinite yield possible on 'X:WaitForChild("Y")', where X is the parent name and Y is the child object name.
> - This function does not yield if a child with the given name exists when the call is made.
> - This function is less efficient than Instance:FindFirstChild or the dot operator. Therefore, it should only be used when the developer is not sure if the object has replicated to the client. Generally this is only the first time the object is accessed

You can remove this warning by adding a `timeout` as a second argument, but you'll need to account for the fact that it's possible that the object isn't found :

```
local timeout = 2 -- seconds
local values = player:WaitForChild('Values', timeout)
if values then
    local boolVal = values.Claimed
    print("Claimed = ", boolVal.Value)
    -- mark it as claimed
    boolVal.Value = true
else
    warn("Could not find 'Values' BoolValue")
end
```

Alternatively, if you know that `Values` will exist at the time this code will execute, you can simply access it with the dot operator or with the `FindFirstChild()` function. But this will throw an "Attempt to index nil" error if `Values` doesn't exist.

```
local boolVal = player:FindFirstChild('Values').Claimed
-- or
local boolVal = player.Values.Claimed

-- mark it as claimed
boolVal.Value = true
```

When you see this warning, you should double check the spelling on the name of the object, as well as the timing of when the script executes to make sure that the object actually exists.